# how to find the id of my contact that i want to edit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of contacts and need to find their id so that I can edit one contact specifically. I don't seem to be able to find the contact's Id.

```
const index = contactsEditedUpdated.findIndex(el => el.id === find);
```

This is the line that doesn't work. I want to assign the el.id to idContact.

```
const editContact = (contactObj, find) => {
    fetch("http://localhost:4000/data", {
      contactObj,
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(contactObj),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        const contactsEditedUpdated = [...contactList];
        const index = contactsEditedUpdated.findIndex(el => el.id === find);
        contactsEditedUpdated[index] = find;
        setContactsEdited(contactList);
        console.log("Good job! u updated ur contact!", res);
      })
      .catch(error =>
        console.error("Uuuu, u messed up! could not update", error)
      );
  };
```

The expected result should be that I get the id of the element that I want to edit. So far, I've only been able to get the id of the element I input through the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you should read up on SOLID principles; specifically Single Responsibility Principle. https://codeburst.io/understanding-solid-principles-single-responsibility-b7c7ec0bf80

You should do the following in separate functions
- Fetch data
- Search for contactId
- Update data

On the data manipulation you appear to be passing the original `contactList` to the `setContactsEdited` function, making your `contactsEditedUpdated` irrelevant.

It's hard for me to tell what you're trying to do with `contactsEditedUpdated`. If you require more help you'll need to give more info/context around where `contactList` comes from and what kind of data structure it is.

Comment: Thanks for the info!!! You are right, I have to do it in separate functions.. I reorganized it yesterday and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the element using find method.

```
const targetContact = contacts.find(elm => elm.id === targetId);
```

This is more of a pseudocode.

Comment: You're assigning elm.id to targetId there. I think you mean elm.id === targetId

Comment: Thanks but that is to find the element, and I needed the id of the element.. now I've broken it down into different steps and it's working better.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the id of the object array that needs to update,

```
const index = contactsEditedUpdated.find((el, index) => {return el.id === findID ? index : null });
```

or else you can loop over the array and update the specified object, ex below

```
const updatedArray = contactsEditedUpdated.map((obj, index) => {
 return obj.id === find ? {...obj, // do alteration } : obj

})
```